# Is there a numpy function to store repeating elements in different arrays in a new array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have 4 2d numpy arrays `arr1, arr2, arr3` and `arr4`. Each of the 4 arrays contain only 4 values `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`. Further the values are unique between arrays at a location. So for example if `arr1[i,j] = a` then the other values cannot have `a` at the same location. What I need is to have new arrays with the same value in each array. I also need the indices since I will use these indices to sort some other data.

I tried using several `if` statements. It works but it is not the most efficient approach. I was wondering if there is a numpy function to do the same.
Here's an example of what I have:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1]])
arr2 = np.array([[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2]])
arr3 = np.array([[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]])
arr4 = np.array([[4,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]])
```

I have 4 arrays `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4` with some measurement data.

```
data1 = np.array([[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]])
data2 = np.array([[20,21,22,23],[24,25,26,27]])
data3 = np.array([[30,31,32,33],[34,35,36,37]])
data4 = np.array([[40,41,42,43],[44,45,46,47]])
```

Here's what I need:

```
new_data1 = np.array([[10,41,32,23],[44,35,26,17]])
new_data2 = np.array([[20,11,42,33],[14,45,36,27]])
new_data3 = np.array([[30,21,12,43],[24,15,46,37]])
new_data4 = np.array([[40,31,22,13],[34,25,16,47]])
```

Comment: please fix the inputs: `np.array([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1])` should be `np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1]])`, etc. (brackets missing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]
data = [data1, data2, data3, data4]

a = np.dstack(arrs)
b = np.dstack(data)

x = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None,None]
y = np.arange(a.shape[1])[None]
z = np.argsort(a, axis=1)

out = list(b[x, y, z].swapaxes(0,1))
```

Output:

```
out[0]
array([[10, 41, 32, 23],
       [44, 35, 26, 17]]),

out[1]
array([[20, 11, 42, 33],
       [14, 45, 36, 27]]),

out[2]
array([[30, 21, 12, 43],
       [24, 15, 46, 37]]),

out[3]
array([[40, 31, 22, 13],
       [34, 25, 16, 47]])
```

Comment: Have you checked the update?

Comment: I did but ran into an error with the dimensions (my actual data is a 317 x 4 array). Still trying to fix that